# T-SQL: Update statement within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that updates the data of table. The stored procedure has optional parameters with NULL default values, like this:

```
@parameter1 datatype = NULL,
@parameter2 datatype = NULL,
@parameter3 datatype = NULL.
```

I need the stored procedure to update the column only if the corresponding parameter is not NULL. I was thinking of doing the following:

```
IF @parameter1 IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE Table 
    SET column1 = @parameter1 
    WHERE id = @id;

IF @parameter2 IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE Table 
    SET column2 = @parameter2 
    WHERE id = @id;

IF @parameter3 IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE Table 
    SET column3 = @parameter3 
    WHERE id = @id;
```

I don't know how efficient this solution would be since there are 42 columns that need to be updated this way. I wonder if there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is whether changing a column to `NULL` is ever a valid operation. There is a difference between not specifying a parameter and explicitly passing `NULL`.

Comment: I would formulate the update within your stored procedure as dynamic sql. You could pass a table_type parameter to your procedure. This parameter could hold all columns you want to update an the corresponding new value. Then you could build a dynamic update statement and execute it within the procedure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you can do ?

```
UPDATE Table 
      SET column1 = coalesce(@parameter1, column1),
          column2 = coalesce(@parameter2, column2), 
          column3 = coalesce(@parameter3, column3)
WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: Note to **José Rodríguez**: this is assuming you're actually updating the same table when you say `UPDATE Table SET ...` in your code snippet.

Comment: Yes, it's only one table

Comment: Be sure to mark this answer as "accepted" if it solves your issue - that will help other people find it.